# SQL: Insert a new unique row based off previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, erp

I'm working with Deltek Vision ERP software trying to create a custom solution to provide a list of deliverables for projects. I've created a custom grid in the Project area of Vision that has a table in SQL structured like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [WBS1]
      ,[WBS2]
      ,[WBS3]
      ,[Seq]
      ,[CreateUser]
      ,[CreateDate]
      ,[ModUser]
      ,[ModDate]
      ,[CustDeliverables]
      ,[CustDueDate]
      ,[CustCompletionDate]
  FROM [Vision_Prod].[dbo].[Projects_Deliverables]
```

The table has three user entered fields, which are the last three columns listed above.

What I'm trying to accomplish is have deliverables set at WBS2 level also roll up to WBS1, so basically what needs to happen is that any time a record is created with a value in WBS2 the record is duplicated but the duplicate has no value in WBS2.

I've setup a workflow in Vision so that when someone enters a deliverable into the grid on a phase it kicks off a stored procedure to accomplish this. The problem is the Seq field. This is a unique identifier the system is assigning when a record is created. When my stored procedure fires I'm getting an error that the sequence has to be included in the record.

This is the stored procedure I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO [Vision_Prod].[dbo].[Projects_Deliverables] (WBS1, WBS2, WBS3, Seq, CreateUser, ModUser, ModDate, CreateDate, CustDueDate, CustCompletionDate)

        SELECT WBS1, '', '', (NEXT VALUE FOR Seq), CreateUser, ModUser, ModDate, CreateDate, CustDueDate, CustCompletionDate 
        FROM Projects_Deliverables
        WHERE Projects_Deliverables.WBS2 IS NOT Null and Projects_Deliverables.WBS1 = @WBS1
```

If anyone can help me figure out how to get the system to assign a new sequence when a record is created in this way that would be most appreciated.

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Almost certainly SQL Server, let me tag it now.

Comment: Presumably `seq` is declared `NOT NULL` with no default value.  You probably want it to be an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the system creates the tables automatically based on how you setup user defined components in the front end, I would presume Seq is created as an Identity column because it is the only one with a unique value.

Comment: if the seq column is an identity, just remove it from the insert, as it'll automatically assign a new unique identity. Unless if the Vision handles it, if so, you could try `newid()` instead of ((NEXT VALUE FOR Seq).

Comment: @iSR5 I was able to get it working using this: REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36)), '-', '')

Comment: @lostdragon05 good to know that you've got it working. and also, I've learned a new technique from you as well ;). so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36)), '-', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dummy table using VALUES to create the an extra row and then fiter out when not needed. Something (but not tested) like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
  [WBS1]
  ,CASE c WHEN 2 THEN NULL ELSE [WBS2] END AS [WBS2] 
  ,[WBS3]
  ,[Seq]
  ,[CreateUser]
  ,[CreateDate]
  ,[ModUser]
  ,[ModDate]
  ,[CustDeliverables]
  ,[CustDueDate]
  ,[CustCompletionDate]
FROM [Vision_Prod].[dbo].[Projects_Deliverables]
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2)) t(c)
WHERE (WBS2 IS NULL AND c < 2)
  OR WBS2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave, but I'm not sure this will accomplish what I need. I have to get the values into the existing table because that is what drives the display in the ERP software. So when they are in Vision looking at a project the users see the grid populated with any rows in the corresponding table that have a WBS1 value but no value in WBS2 (WBS1 is project and WBS2 is phase). When they flip to a phase the grid displays values from this table where WBS1 matches the project they are viewing and WBS2 matches the phase they are viewing.